# Javascript .value is empty when I post to php using axios/vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I have a chat box and underneath I have bb smileys that when you click on them it will add a smiley to the text already in the input box.

But when I post using axios the array is empty, and If I manually enter the smiley bbcode it works.

```
<input id="txtName" @keyup.enter="addMessage" v-model="txtInput" type="text" style="width:100%;height:40px;color:#000000;" placeholder="Type here and hit return">

<a style="cursor: pointer;" title="[smiley]" onClick="document.getElementById('txtName').value +='[smiley]'">
<img src="bb/images/smiley.gif"></img>
</a>  

axios.post('ajax/post.php', 
{ txtInput : this.txtInput }).then(function (response) {
console.log(response);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn’t manually update the **value** of the input.

You should add a click listener and change the v-model property

```
<a @click=“this.txtInput += ‘[smiley]’”
```

Note: you shouldn’t modify the DOM with vanilla JS, but relu on the methods vue exposes.

Comment: I just tried doing that but nothing changed when I clicked it :S

Comment: Turns out I didn't need "this.txtInput" just "txtinput" thanks dude :)